# Ubuntu Core container runtime

Tags: ubuntu-core, container

I would like to use Ubuntu Core with CSPs (Cloud Service Providers)
See Canonical's announcement:
https://ubuntu.com/blog/snappy-ubuntu-core-now-on-aws

As many organizations would be using it with containers I am wondering if it comes bundled with a container run-time like Docker CE, containerd or CRI-O.

Q: Does Ubuntu Core come with a pre-installed container runtime?

Thanks

Comment: @user535773 Thanks.

Comment: @user535733 can you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ubuntu Core does not include a *container runtime*.

The kernel is capable, but runtime software (LXD, Docker, etc) is not included in the normal install of Ubuntu Core.

You must add an LXD or Docker snap to Ubuntu Core to add container functionality. Happily, these are easily available in the snap store.